# Why is my XSL stylesheet for-each not functioning, repeats text

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, xls

I have reviewed the questions that may already have your answer section, and the solutions did not work.

I am pretty new to XML stylesheets, I have an XSL and within my for each loop, the data keeps repeating, when I am trying to get all the text within the tag. It has the count (amount of values within the parent tag) accurate,  but only prints the same text.

Any ideas?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

     <xsl:template match="/programming/languages/language">

        <h3>=======Programming Language <xsl:value-of select="./@id" />=======</h3>
        <p>Language: <xsl:value-of select="name" /></p>

        Intended Use:
        <xsl:variable name="intendedUseID" select="purpose/intendedUse/@id" />
        <xsl:for-each select="/programming/purpose/intendedUse[@id=$intendedUseID]" >
           <xsl:value-of select="/programming/purpose/intendedUse" />
        </xsl:for-each>

        <br />

        <xsl:variable name="featureID" select="features/feature/@id" />
             <xsl:for-each select="/programming/features/feature[@id=$featureID]">
                <xsl:value-of select="/programming/features/feature" /><br />
            </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<programming>
  <languages>
    <language id="1">
      <name>C</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="2" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="4" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="4" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="1" />
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="2">
      <name>C++</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="2" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="5" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="3">
      <name>C#</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="5" />
        <intendedUse id="6" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="5" />
        <feature id="6" />
        <feature id="7" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="3" />
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="4">
      <name>Java</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="6" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="5" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="4" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="5">
      <name>JavaScript</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="3" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="6">
      <name>PHP</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="5" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="7">
      <name>Python</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
        <intendedUse id="10" />
        <intendedUse id="11" />
        <intendedUse id="12" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="5" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="8">
      <name>Basic</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="13" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="4" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="1" />
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="9">
      <name>ADA</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="2" />
        <intendedUse id="14" />
        <intendedUse id="15" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="5" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="1" />
        <standard id="2" />
        <standard id="6" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="10">
      <name>ActionScript 3.0</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="7" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="3" />
      </standards>
    </language>
  </languages>

  <purpose>
    <intendedUse id="1"> Application</intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="2"> System </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="3"> General Purpose </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="4"> Low-Level Operations </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="5"> RAD </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="6"> Business </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="7"> Client-Side </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="8"> Server-Side </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="9"> Web </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="10"> Scripting </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="11"> AI </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="12"> Scientific Computing </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="13">Education</intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="14">Embedded</intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="15">RealTime</intendedUse>
  </purpose>
  <features>
    <feature id="1">Imperative </feature>
    <feature id="2">Object-Oriented</feature>
    <feature id="3">Functional</feature>
    <feature id="4">Procedural</feature>
    <feature id="5">Generic</feature>
    <feature id="6">Reflective</feature>
    <feature id="7">Event-Driven</feature>
  </features>
  <standards>
    <standard id="1">ANSI</standard>
    <standard id="2">ISO</standard>
    <standard id="3">ECMA</standard>
    <standard id="4">DE FACTO</standard>
    <standard id="5">NO</standard>
    <standard id="6">GOST</standard>
  </standards>
</programming>
```

This is what prints out

=======Programming Language 1=======

Language: C

Intended Use: Application Application Application Application
Imperative
Imperative

=======Programming Language 2=======

Language: C++

Intended Use: Application Application

Imperative
Imperative
Imperative
Imperative
Imperative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing:

`<xsl:for-each select="/programming/purpose/intendedUse[@id=$intendedUseID]" >`

puts you in the context of `intendedUse`. From this context, you just need to grab the value of the current node by doing:

```
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

The way you have it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/programming/purpose/intendedUse" />
```

goes back to the root and selects the **first** node on this path.

The second thing is that when your first and only template starts in the middle of the input tree, the higher-up nodes and their descendants will be handled by the [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule).

As a result, you will accumulate a lot of garbage text in the result because by default, all text nodes are copied to the output tree. You should make your first template match the root node:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

and change the included paths to start from there.

Finally, you should consider using [keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) to lookup data from other branches of the document: it's neater and more efficient, too.

Comment: Wow, just one little period.. thanks! i will look into using keys!